Python FastAPI share DB connection with subrouter
My folder structure looks like this:
-/main.py
-/db.py
--/routers/
---device.py
---/operations/
----backup.py

So, there's two files, db.py and main.py, a folder called routers, which holds a file called device.py and another folder called operations. Inside operations, I've got a file, backup.py.
main.py looks like this:
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

# Import routers
from routers import device

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return RedirectResponse(url=f"{request.url}docs/")

# Load routers
app.include_router(device.router)

Inside device.py:
### Device API Router
from fastapi import APIRouter

# Import custom classes
from . import db
from routers.operations import backup

# Parse the DB config
db_pool = db() # This initializes a pool of MySQL connections using the db.py file

router = APIRouter()

# Import subrouters
router.include_router(backup.router)

Now, obviously, inside the "subrouter" backup I have some routes configured as a router. I want to use that DB connection variable inside this router. How can I do that, without loading the db.py file again, which would create a different pool of connections?
The end goal is to have a single pool of 10 - 20 connections, whatever, that I can share across "subrouters", instead of having each router with his own pool of connections.
Simply put, I have a variable in the device.py file that I want to "share"/"send"/"borrow" inside the operations/backup.py file.
The reason for doing this is that I want to "split" my API into multiple files, each based on the operation they perform - I suppose this is a pretty standard practice. I'm planning to have /device/backup/, /device/network/, /device/state/. I want those routers (backup, network, state) to be in different files, to keep everything nice and clean.
Hoping I made that clear.
Thank you!

Create database.py and import the db_pool from that file? Importing it in multiple locations does not execute the code multiple times, it just makes the symbols available. You could also consider using FastAPI's dependency system to get a db connection from your pool when needed instead of having global state in your application: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency

My point is that you can create the pool in a separate module, and then use that (you can do this in your application file for example, or in a separate module) - if you don't want to create a default pool in your db-file.

So, you mean, instead of having a module that's called from another file (the router file), I should have the DB module that sort of calls itself, forms the DB object and then import that file into any files where DB access is required? Did I get that right?

For example, you could create the instance right after creating your db class (which, depending on how advanced it is, might not be necessary - you could just set up the pool directly instead), or you could have a separate database_instance.py file which imports db.py and create the pool, and then you import the pool from that module.
